# How to POST an object with a file attached in WebAPI?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, attachment

I'm using **AngularJS** to build my application. In it, I have a form that the user can fill with information. That creates an object that POSTs to a database using WebAPI.

Here's the Angular code:

```
$scope.test_object =
{
    'Title': $scope.test_object.title,
    'Description': $scope.test_object.description,
};

// POST to the database
$http.post(some_url, JSON.stringify($scope.test_object)).then(function (response) {
        // do something
    }
);
```

And here's my class in Visual Studio:

```
public class ClassName
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

This works as it should with no problems. My problem is that the form has the capability of attaching a file. I have a controller in Visual Studio to send the file, here's the code:

```
public class FileUploadController : ApiController
{

    [Route("api/upload")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            //Save To this server location
            var uploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Data");

            //Save file via CustomUploadMultipartFormProvider
            var multipartFormDataStreamProvider = new CustomUploadMultipartFormProvider(uploadPath);

            // Read the MIME multipart asynchronously 
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(multipartFormDataStreamProvider);

            // Show all the key-value pairs.
            foreach (var key in multipartFormDataStreamProvider.FormData.AllKeys)
            {
                foreach (var val in multipartFormDataStreamProvider.FormData.GetValues(key))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val));
                }
            }

            //In Case you want to get the files name
            //string localFileName = multipartFormDataStreamProvider
            //    .FileData.Select(multiPartData => multiPartData.LocalFileName).FirstOrDefault();

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(e.Message)
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I found this code online and it works for sending files. This sends any file to the specified folder (/Data).

**Now my question is: how do I create a relationship between the object and the attachment?** How can I tell which files are associated with each object? Do I send the object ID along with the file somehow?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do in these situations is save the address of where the file is kept in a property of the object. So for instances, you could add a property to your class like this:

```
public class ClassName
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

And then when you write your file to a directory you copy the address of the file to the FilePath property.